# List elements are being added in AsyncTask even if I try to empty it

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, android-asynctask

So, I have some code which I think is far from great, but right now I have one particularly interesting problem.

I use PkRSS for populating a List. every time I change the Fragment back and forth, the List adds the newly fetched items on top, even if I call `Collections.emptyList()` right before populating it.

Heres the Code:

```
public class UpcommingFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String rss = "XYZ.RSS";
    public static List<Article> rssItems = Collections.emptyList();
    public RecyclerAdapter recAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recList;

    public UpcommingFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler, container, false);

        recList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
//        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(rssItems);
        recList.setAdapter(recAdapter);


        recList.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Article a;

                        a = rssItems.get(position);

                        String date = a.getDescription().substring(0, 12);
                        String uri = String.valueOf(a.getSource());

                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), EventDetailActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("date", date);
                        i.putExtra("head", a.getTitle());
                        i.putExtra("url", uri);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
        );

        new RSSget().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        rssItems = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (NetworkInfo anInfo : info)
                    if (anInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // AsyncTask
    private class RSSget extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                rssItems = Collections.emptyList();
                rssItems = PkRSS.with(getActivity()).load(rss).get();
                Log.e("LISTCOUNTER", String.valueOf(rssItems.size()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Error", "eror");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            recAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(rssItems);
            recList.setAdapter(recAdapter);
        }
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

and heres the LogCat

```
    09-12 11:33:08.050  23259-23329/com.mikebdev.douala E/LISTCOUNTER﹕ 12
09-12 11:33:11.701  23259-23306/com.mikebdev.douala E/LISTCOUNTER﹕ 24
09-12 11:33:15.017  23259-23323/com.mikebdev.douala E/LISTCOUNTER﹕ 36
```

As you can see, every time i change the fragment back and forth, the List adds those 12 elements on top.

And of course I would be thankful if you find anything I could do better in this code

If you need to see anything else, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with PkRSS, but a quick glimpse at its github page, it seems that this is some kind of stateful RSS reader. Perhaps you cannot simply just invoke its load method without clearing its previously read data?

Comment: `if (rssItems.isEmpty()) {
                    rssItems = PkRSS.with(getActivity()).load(rss).get();
                }`  You are right

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        recAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(rssItems);
        recList.setAdapter(recAdapter);
recAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
    }
}
```